# Compiling Mitsuba 2 on Visual Studio 2022 (SCons error)

Tags: python, visual-studio-2022, scons

I try to build the `mitsuba-msvc2010.sln` using Visual Studio 2022. I fail to successfully build this solution; most probably due to some changes in SCons. This is the error I obtain

> AttributeError: 'SConsEnvironment' object has no attribute 'has_key':
> 1>  File "SConstruct", line 15: 1>    env =
> SConscript('build/SConscript.configure') 1>  File "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\site-packages\SCons\Script\SConscript.py",
> line 662: 1>    return method(*args, **kw) 1>  File "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\site-packages\SCons\Script\SConscript.py",
> line 598: 1>    return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw) 1>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\site-packages\SCons\Script\SConscript.py",
> line 285: 1>    exec(compile(scriptdata, scriptname, 'exec'),
> call_stack[-1].globals) 1>  File "build\SConscript.configure", line
> 111: 1>    if env.has_key('BOOSTINCLUDE'):

Was anybody able to build this and/or knows how to fix this problem?

Comment: If you wrap your code snippet in triple backquotes, it will render better.

Comment: Can you add a link to a git repo for the sources?

Answer (score 2):

Python 3 dictionary objects no longer supports the `has_key` method, so that SConscript is out of date.  The membership test "`in`" can be used instead, as in `if 'BOOSTINCLUDE' in env:`.  There may be other things that need to be "ported" to use modern Python and SCons, usually not too complicated.